# Как вводить в scanf_s?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Вот такой вот простой код на C в Visual Studio

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    printf("Введите данные:\n");
    char name[5];
    char vid;
    int area;
    scanf_s("%s", name, 5);
    scanf_s("%c", &vid, 1);
    scanf_s("%d", &area);

    printf("%s, %c, %d", name, vid, area);
```

Я не могу нормально ввести значение `vid` , потому что, когда я ввожу 4 символа `name`, я ставлю пробел и он считается за символ, если *enter*, тоже считает как символ переноса. Есть способ как-то адекватно вводить данные, чтобы через пробел или *enter*, или для это придётся каждый раз прописывать вывод *"\n"* ?
А если сделать ввод одной строчкой вот так
`scanf_s("%s, %c, %d", name, 5, &vid, 1, &area);`, то он вообще нормально не вводит, все данные кроме первой строки *name* берёт по умолчанию, я не понимаю, как это работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать ввод на C в Visual Studio без `#define SRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` а именно, используя `scanf_s`.

Comment: `"%c"` → `" %c"`

Comment: Блин, спасибо, и ведь знал же, но чё то затупил прям. Спасибо больше